# TSQL efficiency - INNER JOIN replaced by EXISTS

Tags: t-sql

Can the following be rewritten to be more efficient?
I would use `EXISTS` if I didn't need fields from `country` but I do need those fields, and am not sure how to write this to make it more efficient.

```
SELECT      distinct 
        p.ProvinceID,
        p.Abbv as RegionCode,
        p.name as RegionName,
        cn.Code as CountryCode,
        cn.Name as CountryName
 FROM         dbo.provinces AS p 

                  INNER JOIN dbo.Countries AS cn ON p.CountryID = cn.CountryID
                  INNER JOIN dbo.Cities c on c.ProvinceID = p.ProvinceID
                  INNER JOIN dbo.Listings AS l ON l.CityID = c.CityID

WHERE l.IsActive = 1 AND l.IsApproved = 1
```

Comment: post the structure of your tables and expected result from the query, hard to help with the question as it is now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to note:

1. You're joining to `dbo.Listings` which results in many records, so you need to use `DISTINCT` (usually an expensive operator)
2. For any tables with columns not in the select you can move into an `EXISTS` (but the query planner effectively does this for you anyway)

So try this:

```
SELECT       
        p.ProvinceID,
        p.Abbv as RegionCode,
        p.name as RegionName,
        cn.Code as CountryCode,
        cn.Name as CountryName
 FROM  dbo.provinces AS p 
       INNER JOIN 
       dbo.Countries AS cn 
       ON p.CountryID = cn.CountryID
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM 
               dbo.Listings l 
               INNER JOIN dbo.Cities c 
               on l.CityID = c.CityID
               WHERE  c.ProvinceID = p.ProvinceID
               AND l.IsActive = 1 AND l.IsApproved = 1 
              )
```

Check the query plans before and after - the query planner might be smart enough to do this anyway, but you *have* removed your `distinct`

Comment: I am using distinct because i only want ONE province for each, what you proposed brings back multiple because of inner join.  That was the reason I was using distinct to just give me one record per province.

In short i am trying to get list of provinces that have listings, this is done by being related to city, and city being related to listing, and listing having those two clauses to determine if its considered listing or not

Comment: I will change the query. It really helps if you provide sample data then we don't have to go back and forth.

Answer (score -1):

The following will often perform even better by providing the optimizer more useful information:

```
SELECT       
        p.ProvinceID,
        p.Abbv as RegionCode,
        p.name as RegionName,
        cn.Code as CountryCode,
        cn.Name as CountryName
 FROM  dbo.provinces AS p 
       INNER JOIN 
       dbo.Countries AS cn 
       ON p.CountryID = cn.CountryID
      INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            p.ProvinceID
        FROM  
           dbo.Listings l 
           INNER JOIN dbo.Cities c 
           on l.CityID = c.CityID
           WHERE l.IsActive = 1 AND l.IsApproved = 1 
        GROUP BY
            p.ProvinceID
      ) list
    on list.ProvinceID = p.ProvinceID
```

Comment: I am curios why you are being downvoted, will that outperform the accepted answer?

Comment: @Zoinky: Possibly - it potentially reduces a nested loop's iteration count. Do a showplan for both and see if there is a difference with your table structure.